# Need advice with outlook vbs rule to read header and assign category

Tags: vbscript, outlook

Found this great script that can add a rule to Outlook but I would like to create the following rule and would like some help modifying

Outlook Rule:
Apply this rule after the message arrives
with **external** in the message header
assign it to the **EXTERNAL** category

```
Const RULE_NAME = "test"
Const olRuleReceive = 0
Const olFolderSentMail = 5
Dim olkApp, olkSes, olkCol, olkRul, olkCD1, olkCD2, olkMRA
On Error Resume Next
Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olkSes = olkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olkSes.Logon olkApp.DefaultProfileName
Set olkCol = olkSes.DefaultStore.GetRules()
Set olkRul = olkCol.Item(RULE_NAME)
If Typename(olkRul) = "Empty" Then
    Set olkRul = olkCol.Create(RULE_NAME, olRuleReceive)
    Set olkCD1 = olkRul.Conditions.From
    With olkCD1
        .Enabled = True
        .Recipients.Add olkSes.CurrentUser.Address
        .Recipients.ResolveAll
    End With
    Set olkCD2 = olkRul.Exceptions.ToOrCc
    With olkCD2
        .Enabled = True
    End With
    Set olkMRA = olkRul.Actions.MoveToFolder
    With olkMRA
        .Enabled = True
        Set .Folder = olkSes.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    End With
    olkCol.Save False
End If
olkSes.Logoff
olkApp.Quit
Set olkMRA = Nothing
Set olkCD2 = Nothing
Set olkCD1 = Nothing
Set olkRul = Nothing
Set olkCol = Nothing
Set olkSes = Nothing
Set olkApp = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```